# ClassCastException: cannot be cast to NewsItem

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

newsitem is a class that hold my data.
when I click an item in the list view I get this error:

```
01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.example.NewsItem

01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.example.ListViewContents$2.onItemClick(ListViewContents.java:72)

01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)

01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1037)

01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2449)

01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3085)

01-19 11:03:20.094: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3591)
```

---

when clicked should be open an activity.

this is onCreate method in the my ListviewContents class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listviewcontents);
    intent = getIntent();
    url_topic = intent.getIntExtra("key", 0);
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    adapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(this,arraylist_newitems);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button buttonrefresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_refresh);
    buttonrefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    new LongImageFetch().execute((Void)null);

     listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                String url ;
                NewsItem newitem = (NewsItem) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                url = newitem.getUrllink();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URL", url);
                startActivity(intent);
              }
            });

}
```

Comment: You haven't given the code for the `NewsItem` class, but I am assuming it's something moderately complex with at least a couple of fields. How/why do you expect Java to be able to cast an integer to a NewsItem?

Comment: can you show where `arraylist_newitems` is declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.example.NewsItem
```

`listview.getItemAtPosition(position);` returns a Integer value.

But you have

```
NewsItem newitem = (NewsItem) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
// casting it to  NewsItem
```

You probably want

```
NewsItem newitem = (NewsItem)arraylist_newitems.get(position)
```

Comment: Object android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(int position)

(document)

Comment: @user3103823 you probably want  `NewsItem newitem = (NewsItem)arraylist_newitems.get(position)`

Comment: @user3103823 your excpetion is clear casting integer to NewsItems and try the suggestion in my comment.

Comment: solved, tnx Raghunandan. I've changed to NewsItem newitem = (NewsItem)arraylist_newitems.get(position) ;

Comment: when I click on increase vote I get this message : Vote Up requires 15 reputation.

Comment: @user3103823 see the tick mark at left top corner of this answer... check that to accept... accepting does not require any higher reputation...

Answer (score 0):

The OnItemClickListener passes you the view to use as a parameter.

Does this work:

```
NewsItem newitem = (NewsItem)view;
```

?

Comment: your suggestion is NewsItem newitem = (NewsItem) view.getItemAtPosition(position); ?

Comment: If your list is a list of of NewsItem, the view parameter will be the one they clicked. just use (NewsItem)view;  But if your list is a list of other view's that contain NewsItem, do (NewsItem)view.findViewById(R.id.news_item). Maybe you could post the layouts you use if this comment doesn't help.